# Insert a block into a template

Tags: views, 8, theming

How a block already created (with Views) I could insert into my template (mytemplate.html.twig)?

Comment: @NishantP thank you but I need for Drupal 8

Comment: Check this : https://www.drupal.org/node/2354645

Comment: I didn't work with template structure of D8 yet. But I think this can be done using setting a variable containing block html for template file and use it in `mytemplate.html.twig`.

Comment: You probably have to preprocess function to pass the block into template that you want to added it.